# Firebase Analytics Error Cannot create Value type with unsupported value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to log a few events, but the console is telling me there are errors. Here's a couple of events I'm trying to log:

```
Analytics.logEvent("workout_velocities", parameters: [
  "workout_uuid": UUID().uuidString,
  "speed": [
    "2018-02-22 07:46:37 +0000": -1,
    "2018-02-22 07:46:38 +0000": -1,
    "2018-02-22 07:46:39 +0000": -1
  ]
])
```

I get the following error message:

```
2018-02-21 23:52:42.480336-0800 RunManager[1878:1120392] 4.8.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS035001] Cannot create Value type with unsupported value. The Value has to be NSNumber or NSString. Value: {
"2018-02-22 07:46:37 +0000" = "-1";
"2018-02-22 07:46:38 +0000" = "-1";
"2018-02-22 07:46:39 +0000" = "-1";
}
2018-02-21 23:52:42.480414-0800 RunManager[1878:1120392] 4.8.1 -     [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS016000] Event parameter value must be of type     NSString or NSNumber. Type: _TtGCs26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionarySSSi_
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read the API documentation for [Analytics.logEvent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Classes/Analytics#/c:objc(cs)FIRAnalytics(cm)logEventWithName:parameters:).  For the `parameters` argument it says:

> The dictionary of event parameters. Passing nil indicates that the
>   event has no parameters. Parameter names can be up to 40 characters
>   long and must start with an alphabetic character and contain only
>   alphanumeric characters and underscores. **Only NSString and NSNumber
>   (signed 64-bit integer and 64-bit floating-point number) parameter
>   types are supported.** NSString parameter values can be up to 100
>   characters long. The "firebase_", "google_", and "ga_" prefixes are
>   reserved and should not be used for parameter names.

Your argument doesn't meet the stated requirements.  It appears you're passing a dictionary with values containing things other than strings and numbers.  Specifically, you're passing a "speed" value which contains yet another dictionary.

Comment: I'm sure I can send Bundles inside Bundles in Android. Why can't I do this in iOS?